# A more efficient solution for solving this matrix puzzle?

Tags: python, matrix, puzzle

Find the 3x3 matrix, M, whose rows, columns and diagonals add up to 15. Condition: you must use every number from 1-9.

I'm not very clever, so I just tried this brute force method:

```
def solve_999():
    for a in range(1, 10):
        for b in range(1, 10):
            for c in range(1, 10):
                for d in range(1, 10):
                    for e in range(1, 10):
                        for f in range(1, 10):
                            for g in range(1, 10):
                                for h in range(1, 10):
                                    for i in range(1, 10):
                                        if (a+b+c == d+e+f == g+h+i == a+d+g == b+e+h == c+f+i == a+e+i == c+e+g == 15):                                           
                                            if check_unique([a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]):
                                                print(a, b, c)
                                                print(d, e, f)
                                                print(g, h, i)
                                                return


def check_unique(L):
    d = {1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0}
    for letter in L:
        d[letter] += 1
        if d[letter] > 1:
            return False
    return True
```

It works, but it isn't very efficient. Can anyone help me find a more efficient solution?

Comment: In the `b` loop you can skip the current value of `a`. In the `c` loop, skip the current value of `a` and `b`. And so on. This will make each inner iteration that much smaller, and you don't need to use `check_unique`.

Comment: problem #1 is that `if (a+b+c == d+e+f == g+h+i == a+d+g == b+e+h == c+f+i == a+e+i == c+e+g == 9):` should be `==15`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest speedup you will get will be from generating your squares so that they are already unique. The easiest way to do this is `itertools.permutations`. This will reduce you to checking 9! == 362880 boards rather than 387420489 boards (about 1/1000th the work) and you don't have to check to make sure they are unique.

```
from itertools import permutations
t1=time()
for board in permutations(list(range(1,10)),9):
    if sum(board[0:3]) == 15:
        if sum(board[3:6])== 15:
            if board[0]+board[3]+board[6]==15:
                if board[1]+board[4]+board[7]==15:
                    if board[0]+board[4]+board[8]==15:
                        if board[2]+board[4]+board[6]==15:
                            print(board[0:3])
                            print(board[3:6])
                            print(board[6:9])
                            break
```

One major problem with this solution is that we are still checking a ton more cases than we need to. Something to notice is that for each (a,b,d,e) there exists a maximum of 1 value for each of c, f, g, h, and i. This means that we only have to check through 9P4 == 3024  possibilities. The downside of this is that we lose guarantee that all the values are unique. But even if we add this checks, we still see another 10x speedup over our simpler code.

```
def solve_999():
    for a,b,d,e in permutations(range(1,10),4):
        c = 15 - (a + b)
        f = 15 - (d + e)
        g = 15 - (a + d)
        h = 15 - (b + e)
        i = 15 - (a + e)
        if 15 == g+h+i == c+f+i == c+e+g:
            if len(set([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]))==9:
                 print(a, b, c)
                 print(d, e, f)
                 print(g, h, i)
                 print()
                 break
```

To time the code:

```
from timeit import timeitrom itertools import permutations
def solve_999():
    for a,b,d,e in permutations(range(1,10),4):
        c = 15 - (a + b)
        f = 15 - (d + e)
        g = 15 - (a + d)
        h = 15 - (b + e)
        i = 15 - (a + e)
        if 15 == g+h+i == c+f+i == c+e+g:
            if len(set([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]))==9:
                return
print(timeit(solve_999, number=1000))
```

yields a time of 2.9 seconds/10000 tries == .00029 sec/try

Comment: Good idea to show the math, though I'd add the "9<sup>9</sup>" that's the larger number (Argh, why don't they support that tag in comments... they do in answers...). Also, you could use steps like `sum(board[0::3])`.

Comment: true. I'm working on a solution 10x faster though, so I may update this, but probably won't.

Comment: By the way, this method is probably way overkill.

Comment: Very nice idea, picking those four and computing the rest. I now measure it as about 48 as fast as mine.

Comment: In many ways, it is just an extension of what both of our first instincts were: don't generate sequences that can't work. The only difference is that it turns out 9c4 is significantly smaller than 9! (and about half of the conditions we checked are defined to be true).

Comment: One thing I just realized: You're not checking whether the computed five numbers are all in the range 1 to 9. It appears to be correct, but I don't think it's trivial.

Comment: Originally, I was, but it didn't do anything, so I took it out. It may be trivial for some reason that I can't figure out, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Its easy. Just think how many ways are there to build 15 out of a sum of three numbers.

```
1+5+9, 1+6+8, 2+4+9, 2+5+8, 2+6+7, 3+4+8, 3+5+7, 4+5+6
```

Each sum appears in your square because there are only 8 ways.
5 must be in the center because it appears 4 times. 
2,4,6,8 must be in the corner because they appear 3 times.

Go on and you find the solution just with thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Bit shorter than the others:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> for a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i in permutations(range(1, 10)):
        if 15 == a+b+c == d+e+f == a+d+g == b+e+h == a+e+i == c+e+g:
            print(a, b, c)
            print(d, e, f)
            print(g, h, i)
            break

2 7 6
9 5 1
4 3 8
```

The search takes about 0.009 seconds on my PC. Measured as follows, it takes about 9 seconds for doing it 1000 times:

```
from itertools import permutations
from timeit import timeit

def solve_999():
    for a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i in permutations(range(1, 10)):
        if 15 == a+b+c == d+e+f == a+d+g == b+e+h == a+e+i == c+e+g:
            return

print(timeit(solve_999, number=1000))
```

Comment: Oh, that's smart, you don't need to check sum(g,h,i) because the first two guarantee it together.

Comment: Can you time mine for me? I wonder if there is something making the times different, because they should be pretty similar timewise

Comment: It turns out that it doesn't (noticeably) effect performance because it is only run in 7/1000ths of the time.

Comment: I found the performance difference. I find all of the solutions, yours only finds 1. The question is actually ambiguous as to which is right.

Comment: @OscarSmith Timing your original one I got about 0.023 seconds. With your improved one, about 0.022 seconds. Really timing only the search, btw, not the printing.

Comment: @OscarSmith I find the question pretty clear, as there's a `return` right after printing the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the itertools.permutations library to iterate over all possibilities checking for your required sums.

While your code works for fixed size of input array  (in this case 3x3 = 9), I have generalized it to check for any given sum over any range that is provided through the use of some python assisted splicing. Note that the length of the input needs to be a perfect square for this to work.

```
from itertools import permutations
from math import sqrt

def check_magic_square(rangeallowed,sumMS):
    sidelenght = int(sqrt(len(rangeallowed)))
    for i in permutations(rangeallowed):
        # initialize all conditions to be satisfied
        MSConditionsSatisfied = True
        # Check for forward diagonal sum
        if (MSConditionsSatisfied and sum(i[::sidelenght+1]) != sumMS): MSConditionsSatisfied = False
        # Check for reverse diagonal sum
        if (MSConditionsSatisfied and sum(i[sidelenght-1:-1:sidelenght-1]) != sumMS): MSConditionsSatisfied = False
        for j in range(sidelenght):
            # Check for each column
            if (MSConditionsSatisfied and sum(i[j::sidelenght]) != sumMS): MSConditionsSatisfied = False
            # Check for each row
            if (MSConditionsSatisfied and sum(i[j*sidelenght:(j+1)*sidelenght]) != sumMS): MSConditionsSatisfied = False
        # if all conditions are satisfied, return the splice reshaped to be a square matrix
        if MSConditionsSatisfied: return [[i[k*sidelenght + j] for j in range(sidelenght)] for k in range(sidelenght)]
    return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(check_magic_square(range(1,10),15))
```

returns

> [[2, 7, 6], [9, 5, 1], [4, 3, 8]]

Time taken on my i5 machine 0.1 seconds